# Passwordless authentication in Flutter with Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, password-less

I've been looking in to passwordless authentication methods for my app for the simplest singup experience possible and I'm a little confused.
Ideally I want something that works on both android and iOS (masOS would be appreciated), but I can always use a platform specific method

I stumbled across this article https://developers.google.com/identity/passkeys but I am a little skeptical.
In the example app they show, passkeys seem to be used as an alternative sign in method, with normal email + password still being an option

So my questions are as follows: Is this stable enough to be used as your primary authentication method and is this safe to use in production yet?

...should I just go with simple email link verification instead?

Comment: Have you explored [Authenticate with Firebase Anonymously](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/anonymous-auth)? That sounds like it would be a good fit and works across all platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settled on email link auth
Passkeys seems a little too bleeding-edge, at least right now

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For your mobile app authentication flow, can implement passkeys as

1- an auto-sign in; i.e. loading the app would trigger the biometric authentication modal where user would use their passkey to log in.

2- Single factor, where user action such as a sign-in button that could be passwordless

3- 2nd factor authentication, where you could layer a password/OTP based login flow with a passkey authentication.
To address this issue, we have developed a firebase extension for passkeys called justpass.me. It is a very simple and powerful way to enable passwordless biometric authentication into your Firebase web and mobile apps.

please take a look at this [extension](https://extensions.dev/extensions/justpass-me/justpass-me) where you can integrate passkeys into Firebase and [flutter](https://www.justpass.me/docs/mobile/Flutter) in few easy steps.

Comment: Looks interesting, I'll have a look